# Symfony3 and gmail on localhost

Tags: php, email, localhost, symfony

I am new to Symfony3, and I need to send an email (using gmail). I'm working on localhost. I have configured my **config_dev.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    host:      smtp.gmail.com
    port:      465
    username:  example@gmail.com
    password:  mypassword
```

and **parameters.yml** with

```
 mailer_user: example@gmail.com
 mailer_password: password
```

Controller

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('medicalguidesystem@gmail.com')
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setBody(
                'You have been registered in MedicalGuide system as a doctor. Username: '.$user->getUsername().' Password: '. $user->getPassword()
            )
        ;
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

But it doesn't send any emails.
Can anyone help me, please? Maybe I forgot something, or doing something wrong. Can emails be sent from localhost?

UPDATE
logs

```
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html you should not need to set host or port, just transport gmail

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting:

> "Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1"

indicates that Swiftmailer seems to think that it should be using localhost (127.0.0.1) to send mail.

Your problem seems to be that the configuration you specified is not being read in by the Swiftmailer component. My guess is that the environment is not being set correctly so you *think* you're in **dev** but instead Symfony may be running in a different environment.

You can test this by putting the Swiftmailer configuration in the main config file and if that works, follow the [Symfony configuration guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/configuration.html) to ensure that your dev environment is property set up and that you're running the application in that environment (i.e using `http://localhost/app_dev.php..`)

Another useful resource: [How to Organize Configuration Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html)